# Grails MongoDB Optimistic Locking in updating all records

Tags: mongodb, grails, optimistic-locking

I have a daily scheduled grails job which updates the properties of users with changes from last date. It goes like this

```
try {
        // Daily job for updating user orders
        DateTime yesterday = new DateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).withTimeAtStartOfDay().minusDays(1)
        userService.updateStatsForAllUsers(yesterday)
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        println e.getCause()
    }
```

UserService

```
void updateStatsForAllUsers(DateTime date) {
    List<User> customers = User.list()
    List<Order> orders = null
    customers.each { customer ->
        orders = customer.orders?.findAll{it.status.equals("DELIVERED")}?.sort{it?.dateCreated}
        if (orders?.size() > 0) {
            customer.firstOrderDate = orders?.first()?.dateCreated
            customer.lastOrderDate = orders?.last()?.dateCreated
            customer.totalOrders = orders.size()
            customer.save(flush: true)
        }
    }
}
```

We have a user base of around 50k, and this job always throws a OptimisticLockingException on user save., how can we handle this, is there any way for such batch update using grails mongo.